# Qt двойной QMessageBox

Tags: qt

У меня в приложении при нажатии на кнопку "закрыть", вылазиет QMessageBox. Если при этом до этого была заполнена форма, если нет, программа должна показать еще одни QMessageBox с данной ошибкой.

```
void ob_panel::on_pB_Beenden_clicked()
{
   QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Warning,
                tr("ALADIN BKS Simulator"),
                tr("Wollen Sie wirklich ALADIN BKS Simulator beenden?"),
                QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No,
                this);
        messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("Ja"));
        messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("Nein"));

        messageBox.exec();

        if(messageBox.YesRole){
            //TODO
            if(wasOpen == 1){
                QApplication::quit();
            }if(wasOpen == 0){
                QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Critical, tr("ALADIN BKS Simulator"), tr("Es wurde noch kein Flugprotokoll erstellt"), QMessageBox::Ok);
            }
        }else{
            //TODO
            QApplication::quit();
        }
}
```

Первый QMessageBox у меня показывается, а вот второй не хочет. В чем состоит моя ошибка?

Comment: Не очень понял вот эту строчку, мне кажется, именно в ней кроется ошибка - `if(messageBox.YesRole)`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver эта строка работает и отлавливает нажатие по любой кнопки в диалоговом окне, принадлижайшей семейки "YES", т.е та же самая кнока `QMessageBox::Yes`. Почему я знаю что оно работает, так это потому что, с другим диалоговым окном ничего не происходит.

Comment: строка `if(messageBox.YesRole)` эквивалентна `if (5)` то есть выражение не имеет смысла. По сути вопроса подозреваю, что `wasOpen` к этому времени равняется 1 и происходит выход. Советую проверить в отладчике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, для второго сообщения надо добавить вызов

```
if(wasOpen == 0){
            QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Critical, tr("ALADIN BKS Simulator"), tr("Es wurde noch kein Flugprotokoll erstellt"), QMessageBox::Ok).exec();
}
```

Во-вторых `if(messageBox.YesRole)` всегда `true`, надо:

```
if(messageBox.exec()==messageBox.Yes){
```

Comment: Спасибо, первой строки хватило )